# How to include xml prolog to xml files using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, elementtree

I want to include the XML prolog in my XML file...
I tried the following -

```
ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
```

But it works only while printing and not for writing to file.
I have a small code where I am changing an attribute and modifying the XML file. But I want to add the XML prolog also. Any idea how to ?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('xyz.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root[0].text = 'abc'
ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
tree.write('xyz.xml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lxml.etree` does it:

```
import lxml.etree

xml = lxml.etree.parse('xyz.xml')
root = xml.getroot()
root[0].text = 'abc'

with open("xyz2.xml", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8"))

print(open("xyz2.xml", 'r').read())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<note>
  <to>abc</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to add prolog to XML you need to pass additional parameter (`xml_declaration`) to `tree.write()` method as follows:

```
tree.write('xyz.xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

The last but one code line is redundant, so our method should take one more parameter:

```
tree.write('xyz.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

The corrected code will be as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('xyz.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root[0].text = 'abc'
tree.write('xyz.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

P.S. As `enconding` and `xml_declaration` are the second and the third optional named parameters, call of `write` method can be simplified:

```
tree.write('xyz.xml', 'UTF-8', True)
```